# Can an android Service update an Activity-GUI other than the one it was called by?

Tags: android, multithreading, service, kill

1.
I have 2 Activities,

class A { I have called a service}

class Service {I am running in the background. I was called by Class A, but I want to bring Class B in front and add text to Class B}

Class B { I have a nice GUI}

2.
How can I effectively kill "class Service" (from above question), it has a while loop and listening to incoming messages (sent by myServer) ?
Please provide me example with say, when a Button in Class A is clicked... how to check if there is a service already running?!!!
[cause, if I hit hardware back key, class A goes off, still service is running, which is expected for me.]

Tearing my hairs..

Thank you all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `startActivity()` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29) using an Intent and then pass the data for Activity B in the Intent's extras package.

See the http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#stopService%28android.content.Intent%29 for details on stopping the service.